# Creating empty copies of files with new extensions

Tags: files, filenames, aix

I have `AIX 7.1`. Let's say I have a directory with files like these:

```
1.txt
lala.csv
```

I need to create empty copies of these files with a new extension in the same directory, like so:

```
1.txt.done
lala.csv.done
```

I can't seem to find the right option for doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Simply loop over every file (here, skipping dotfiles by default), and touch the corresponding file:

```
for f in *; do touch "${f}.done"; done
```

Comment: could you also clarify what does $ do in this command?

Comment: Sure, @xarenjo ; it introduces a variable expansion. I used curly braces out of habit, to explicitly delineate what the variable is (f). The end result is that the touch command sees the value of `$f` — each existing filename — during each loop.

Comment: Or with redirection : for f in *; do > "${f}.done"; done